# How to restrict the default tool tip width in html

Tags: jquery, css, html

i am using `<a>` tag default title attribute for display tool tip for links.
 but my issue is how to restrict the width of tool tip. This title tag goes out of the window when hove the link.

sample code i provide for this issue http://jsfiddle.net/cj74C/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as as I know there is no standard way to do this. You cannot format the alt/title popup from the browser.

Google says for IE you can put this:

```
&#13;
```

as a carriage return in the text.

If you want flexibility - you probably have to drop the browser standard behavior and utilize jQuery plugins like

http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/

Answer (score 0):

After taking the value from title you can remove this attribute.

```
$(this).removeAttr('title');
```

Or you can store title and then remove it:

```
$(this).data("title", $(this).attr("title")).removeAttr("title");
```